# What is the best way to take input through DMs in a discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot that acts as a foundation for turn-based games that I'm going to make in the future, a game engine of sorts.

Anyway, I need to take input to the bot, through DMs as commands posted to a server could be snooped in on, spoiling games where you need to keep a secret your moves, and I was wondering, as buttons have just been added, do they work in DMs, and if not, what would be the best way to implement commands, or reaction based system?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have little to no knowledge of Discord.js so I would highly recommend you to read through their [guide](https://discordjs.guide/) as it will help you immensely.

Discord.js V13 introduces new features such as `<CommandInteraction>` and, like you mentioned, `<Buttons>` and their respective `<ButtonInteraction>`, with which you can handle input that is only seen by the bot, and reply with messages that are only seen by the `<User>` that triggered these `<Interaction>`s, through the use of the also V13 exclusive ephemeral messages.

If you want to read more about V13 in general, there is this WIP [guide](https://v13-prep.discordjs.guide/) and the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

As for the articles that would probably be more specific to your question there is:

- [Slash Command Handling](https://v13-prep.discordjs.guide/command-handling/)
- [Replying to Slash Commands](https://v13-prep.discordjs.guide/interactions/replying-to-slash-commands.html)
- [Registering Slash Commands](https://v13-prep.discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html)
- [Buttons](https://v13-prep.discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html)